# how to set size of the dojo dropdownselect ?

Tags: dojo, size, drop-down-menu, scrollbar

I am using dojox.form.DropDownSelect (not filtering select) in my page. But I am not able to restrict the height of the dropdown. I tried using size, maxHeght etc. but the drop down leep growing as the list grows.

Is there any way to restrict the height?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there is a convenient, documented, way already there. Did you just try to guess things or did you actually search the API reference?

*In case there is not* you could try inspecting the generated dom structure through Firebug. There is probably a div ot table somewhere in there that you can limit the height via a css rule.

```
#that_drop_down .class_of_the_convenient_div {
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I searched the API. They said 'maxHeight' will fix this. but not actually. As you said a grid is being used at run time. But not able to set css for that < i dont know ;) >.